# How to move my premise windows services into Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-services, background-service

I am moving an existing application into Azure and striving for no code changes. I've moved my websites, and they now run as an app service.

We have several background workers, currently running as windows services that need to run in azure. Most are simple .net framework applicaitons that just connect to the database and manipulate data.

I can make this work with a docker container, but I am wondering if there is another way to get them into azure.

Is there a way to make a webJob that runs continuously, and doesn't need a trigger?

What is the best way to move my windows services into Azure, with no code changes?

Comment: Well, Azure container apps could be a good fit..but even most background workers are triggered by something, so you might be able to migrate them to Azure functions.

Comment: Azure funcitons are the long term plan, but that requires a code change.

Comment: The only way with zero code change is running them in a virtual machine.

Comment: I think I can use a container. I was able to get the web applications out with no code change.